# Can't install posix via npm

Tags: node.js

I am calling

```
npm install posix
```

But I am getting following errors:

```
[root@Node2 ~]# npm install posix
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/posix
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/posix
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan

> posix@4.0.0 install /root/node_modules/posix
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/root/node_modules/posix/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/posix/src/posix.o
In file included from ../src/posix.cc:1:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:316: error: ‘REPLACE_INVALID_UTF8’ is not a member of ‘v8::String’
make: *** [Release/obj.target/posix/src/posix.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/root/node_modules/posix/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/node_modules/posix
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.36
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.6
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Library:https://www.npmjs.com/package/posix

My server: Centos 6.7(x64)

Nodejs: 0.10.36

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Apparently, [you opened an issue](https://github.com/ohmu/node-posix/issues/40) for node-posix, but as you can see in the error message, the problem occurs in the dependency nan. There is an [issue at GitHub](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/issues/414) covering your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running `node-gyp`, you get

> ```
> In file included from ../src/posix.cc:1:
> ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:316: error: ‘REPLACE_INVALID_UTF8’ is not a member of ‘v8::String’
> ```

which means your `node-gyp` is using out-of-date headers.  **Update `node-gyp` by updating `npm` with this command:**

```
npm install -g npm
```

It'll probably take a `sudo` because it's a global install.

---

[Similar problem and solution here](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/issues/414)